# jScrollPane isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I am trying to use jScrollPane, the original scrollbar disappearing  and it is not working!
I already used it in another site about a month ago, and it worked well. The single problam was: The mouse wheel was not worked(Thats my second problem).

Code:

```
<link type="text/css" href="jScrollPane/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jScrollPane/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jScrollPane/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jScrollPane/mwheelIntent.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ $("#body").jScrollPane(); });
</script>
</head>
<body id="body">
```

Comment: You are using a very old version of jquery, try updating to this: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I updated and the old scrollbar appeared again...

Comment: do you still need help with this? It's unclear whether you fixed it or not.

Comment: @vyx.ca, i am facing the same problem, even i am using latest version of jquery which they mentioned above either ways it didnot work...do u know any work around plz.....

Comment: can you create a fiddle. (jsfiddle.net) You're not giving much to work with. The error is either coming from the css of the html markup.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on this same issue and have discovered a couple of things.  I agree that you should use a newer version of jQuery.  If you use 1.8.2, it will work.  However, if you use 1.9.1, you will need to get rid of mWheelIntent.js as there is some issue with it and 1.9.1.  Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

The plugin needs to interact with the css file which contains basic styling of the scroll pane elements. The window.load method, loads all the assets of the page before of running the initialization script. I have used jQuery 1.9.1 for this case.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $(".scroll-pane").jScrollPane();
});
```

I hope this helps. Best regards